# preg_match assistance needed 5

Tags: php, html, regex

I'm trying to figure out a problem for a client that has a programmer stuck on a preg_match.  I'm not particularly good at these, but my solution evidently didn't work.  Here was his request:

Very simple job. Need a regular expression preg_match that matches all cases of a string that are NOT in html tags or part of a link's anchor text.

For example if we have the string :

```
Blah blah needle blah blah <div id='needle'>blah blah <a href='#'>needle</a> blah needle</div>
```

the preg_match should only find 2 instances of needle.

Here was my solution which didn't work for their needs:

```
<?php
// The string
$string = "Blah blah needle blah blah <div id='needle'>blah blah <a href='#'>needle</a> blah needle</div>";

// You need everything outside of the tags, so let's get rid of the tags
// and everything in between.
$new_string = preg_replace("/<.*>.*<\/.*>/msU","",$string);

// Now let's match 'needle'
preg_match_all("/needle/msU",$new_string,$matches);

var_export($matches);
?>
```

I was told it didn't work because it "removed all the html before matching so the
result was unformatted HTML".  I don't know why they can't do $string2 = $string; and store the HTML string elsewhere for later use.  I also don't know why that would matter since it's just a preg_match and not a preg_replace that they're looking for.  I guess if someone can help with just a one-line preg_match_all or something, I would be very appreciative.

Thanks ;]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
$pattern = <<<'LOD'
~
  (?>  ### all that you want to skip ###

      <a\b [^>]*+ >             # opening "a" tag
      (?> [^<]++ | <(?!/a>) )*+ # possible content between "a" tags
      </a>                      # closing "a" tag
    |
      < [^>]++ >                # other tags
   ) (*SKIP)(*FAIL)  # forces the precedent subpattern to fail and 
                     # forbid to retry the substring with another subpattern
|
  needle
~x
LOD;

preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```